# Odd one out–Is “a lush beach” so strange?

Tags: adjectives, collocations

The exercise asks [emphasis mine]:

> Cross out one adjective which **does not collocate** with the noun
>
> 4. unspoilt / scenic / pebbly / rocky coastline
> 5. sandy / pebbly / tropical / rocky / lush beach

As others have pointed out I am rephrasing the question as it did not focus on a single issue.

As a non-native speaker of English I do not immediately spot "obvious collocations". Moreover, a quick google points me to multiple examples of *[lush beaches](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lush%20beaches%22&oq=%22lush%20beaches%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB4yCAgCEAAYFhgeMg0IAxAAGIYDGIAEGIoFMg0IBBAAGIYDGIAEGIoFMg0IBRAAGIYDGIAEGIoF0gEKMTIxMzFqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* or *[pebbly coastline](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pebbly%20coastline%22&sca_esv=1e0a15d19e51fa54&sxsrf=ACQVn0-g0oVrZt7OFVEmxB1IzFZpJFQnmw%3A1708638760981&ei=KMLXZam3O6-oxc8Pvd67yAQ&ved=0ahUKEwip65az97-EAxUvVPEDHT3vDkkQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22pebbly%20coastline%22&gs_lp&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1)*. So let's focus on these two specific examples. Can someone please explain why these do not fit?

> ANSWERS
>   ...
>   4. pebbly
>   5. lush
>   …

Comment: Pebbly, sandy, snow-capped, pebbly, lush, snow-capped, sandy...but not necessarily in that order :)

Comment: This isn't on-topic for the site, unfortunately. Questions should focus on a single specific issue and should not be ones that can be answered by a dictionary.

Comment: It's honestly nothing to do with English, except knowing what the words mean. Can waterfalls be sandy? Can mountains be rocky? Knowing that you can answer the questions in any language. They are lousy questions, by the way.

Comment: @alphabet how can a dictionary answer my question? If I find "pebbly" in a dictionary is it going to list all of the collocations next to it? Unless there's a specific dictionary that might teach me these.

Comment: @DJClayworth How was the question lousy? I was seeking answers and afterwards a meaningful discussion about WHY i.e. pebbly/lush are the odd ones out. That's all.

Comment: @Kobdzio I suggest narrowing this down to a single question and reposting it, while explaining why dictionary definitions have not helped you to answer it.

Comment: It's lousy because for several of the questions all of them might apply. Why shouldn't an island be snow-capped? Why can't you find sandy scenery in the desert?

Comment: @alphabet thank you! Will do that.

Comment: @DJClayworth My thoughts exactly! I understood your first comment as "your question is lousy" and felt a bit attacked. I do feel like the exercise in question is too vague.

Comment: All your coastline choices apply well to coastlines, and beach choices to beaches.

Comment: **lush beach** doesn't work. Foliage is lush. Beaches are not. Of course, in poetry they might be. But this is not poetry. And a coast**line** can't be pebbly. Only a beach or expanse of land can.

Comment: [Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sandy+beach.pebbly+beach%2Clush+beach&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for 'lush beach' outperform those for 'sandy beach' and 'pebbly beach'. Though I find this surprising, the exercise is at best flawed. Also, reasonable references mention 'pebbly coastline'; people who think this is wrong probably dont object to 'boil a kettle'.

Comment: Google Books has plenty of results for "lush beach". Some of these are phrases like "lush beach resort", but there are also plenty of "lush beach" - I guess some are beaches with lots of vegetation nearby, but one meaning of [lush](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lush) is "appealing to the senses", and it also has dialect meanings e.g. as a general term for good things.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would be strange.

'Lush' typically describes a green area with plants, grass, and trees. That doesn't fit an area covered with sand and rocks.

It's true that 'lush' has come to have a wider use in UK slang, and can just mean 'beautiful'. It is said about almost anything from food to people you find attractive. But when using the word about a landscape, one would assume its traditional meaning.